# Get API access_token with username/password for an External Identity user

Tags: api, authentication, login

My client is developing a React Native mobile app that is supposed to use SF REST API on behalf External Identity users. They want a native login system, because OAuth flow is clunky (it opens an external browser and the session expires).

During pre-sales SF used Louie Vuitton website as an example for my client. They said that it uses External Identity under the hood, and that website features a custom form for login/password input.

How do I achieve this? It's said in the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_auth_configure_oauth.htm&type=5) that "Experience Cloud supports all available authorization flows, **except** for the username-password OAuth authorization flow", but LV clearly worked around that.

Username-password flow is working with Admin credentials, but returns the following when I'm passing and Ext Idty credentials:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

Setting IP range as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1530/password-security-token-for-external-users) didn't help me.

Comment: In your React Native mobile app, you could make a SOAP API login request instead

Comment: @BryanAnderson Doesn't work for me either. I think it expects the security token which isn't feasible. "INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."

Comment: You may want to try User-Agent flow https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: @BryanAnderson it's not the same, user-agent still feature an SF-hosted login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Winter '23 Salesforce provides [Credentials Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5) which covers this use case. Another possibility I see is using JWT but haven't explored it in detail.